# React-Admin: How do I best use nested "source" props

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, wordpress-rest-api

I am attempting to get `react-admin` to run on top of the `WordPress REST API`.

Posts `title` response is:

```js
{
  "title": {
    "rendered": "Test"
  }
}
```

And while using `react-admin` components to edit post title:

```js
<TextInput source="title.rendered" label="Title" validate={required()} />
```

The **challenge** happens when submitting the `Edit` Form:

```js
// the request body becomes this...
{
  "title": { "rendered": "Test edited" }
}

// But I need to pass it as follows to work with the REST API...
{
   "title": "Test edited"
}
```

I appreciate any help on solving this problem.

Comment: Hi, you will always have challenge dealing with that form data. If the APi sends you `title.rendered` then how comes it expects to receive `title` only. Sounds like a mismatch there!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response,

here is the API response for fetching a single POST 
{ "id": 14, "title": {"rendered": "test" }, .... }

and for updating a post title, the API accept Body request  as
{"title" : "title updated"} without a nested object "rendered".

i'm stuck here, and let me know your idea.

Comment: That REST API is not consistent, so it's very complex for any client-side interaction. If the `GET` returns `{ "id": 14, "title": {"rendered": "test" }, .... }`, what HTTP Method is accepted to update the post title? Is it `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH`? And is the get & update happening at the same endpoint?

Comment: Regarding to The API doc, i'm able to update the post title using this endpoint `/wp/v2/posts/<id>` with `POST`or `PUT` HTTP Method.
And using `POST /wp/v2/posts` for create a new post

Comment: You know what, this is a complex issue. Why? You have an inconsistent field `"rendered"`. If you have access to making changes to that REST API, please change that. If you can't change it, then you might have to look into using `ReferenceInput`. Best solution is to have a consistent REST API.

Comment: ok, i'll chack
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My solution for that issue was trying to Extend `WordPress REST API` with `custom` rest `fields`

Adding a new field name `title` to modify the existing one.

```
function ra_get_title_unnest( $post, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_the_title( (int) $post['id'] );
}

function ra_add_title_unnest_to_api() {
    register_rest_field( 'post',
        'title',
        ['get_callback' => 'ra_get_title_unnest']
    );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'ra_add_title_unnest_to_api' );
```

then the response body becomes :

```
// without a nested form and in a consistent way
{
   "title": "Test edited"
}
```